# Qt/C++ - Reading a char from a line

Tags: c++, qt

This should be SO easy yet I can't figure it out. I'm doing:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QChar>


QFile filein(filename);
if(filein.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QFile::Text)){
    QTextStream in(&filein);
    QString line = in.readLine();
    _n = QChar::digitValue(line[0]);
    _m = stoi(line[1]);
}
```

Neither of these work: `stoi` is `not defined`, no matter what I include, even though I am using a C++11 compiler, also:

```
cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to 'QChar::digitValue(QCharRef)'
         _n = QChar::digitValue(line[0]);
                                       ^`
```

so that doesn't work either. I also tried `QChar::unicode()` with similar results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
int _n = line[0].digitValue();
```